# how to use function object with an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I want to write a C++ generic algorithm that can work on set, list, map, vector, etc... So this algorithm accepts a container and a function object, so I can check for certain conditions.

This algorithm needs to check the longest series in the container according to a certain condition and return its length.

i am having trouble in passing the function object to the function as i get this error (in the second line in main) :

> "Multiple markers at this line
>     - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void functionA(#0 &, #0 &, #1) '
>     - invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int*&' from an rvalue of type 'std::array::iterator {aka "

i don't understand the problem since there is an operator () , in the function object :\ even if i call the constructor first i still get this error ..

what i tried :

```
template<typename T,typename Predicate>
void functionA(T& it1 , T& end1,Predicate pred){
    for(;it1 != end1; ++it1){
        T it2=it1++;
        if(!pred(*it1,*it2)){
            std::cout << *it1 << "\n" ;
            return;
        }
        }
    std::cout <<"not found" << "\n" ;
}

class FindFirst {
    public:
    FindFirst();
    bool operator()(int f , int s) const {
       return f < s;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::array<int,11> myarray = {1,2,4,7,10,14,3,6,12,24,48};
    functionA(myarray.begin(),myarray.end(),find);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [std::array::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin) returns by value, which is a temporary and can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const (i.e. `T&`).

Change the parameter type of `functionA` to pass-by-value, e.g.

```
template<typename T,typename Predicate>
void functionA(T it1 , T end1,Predicate pred){
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0R1iO2MSebniYy8a)

Comment: i get this error now : undefined reference to `FindFirst::FindFirst()'

Comment: @mamama You need to define it, the constructor. If you have nothing to implement you can just remove the declaration.

Comment: @mamama Congratulations; at least you got advances.